# How to connect Datadog java agent to host?

Tags: java, datadog, apm

I set up datadog java agent with this command.

```
java -javaagent:/path/to/dd-java-agent.jar -jar test.jar
```

After running my application, I get this error.
[image]

It seems like I should have passed API key when setting up java agent. Although I was looking up the official document, I couldn't find the way to pass it. Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need install the agent on host: https://app.datadoghq.com/apm/docs?architecture=host-based&language=java

You can use a container docker for this too: https://app.datadoghq.com/apm/docs?architecture=container-based&collection=Same%20host&environment=docker&language=java

Briefly: You'll need install, or maybe execute a container docker, in machine you run the java application and set de parameter `-javaagent:/path/to/dd-java-agent.jar`

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I passed the parameter.

Comment: Not only the parameter, you need to install the agent on the host as I mentioned in the answer. Did you install the agent on your host? Did you follow the links I indicated?

Comment: Can we instead use the dd-java-agent library, without installing the jar on host? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datadoghq/dd-java-agent/1.6.0